# How to get a document library URL from an SPSite object?

Tags: 2007, development, spsite

I have some documents in a document library in SharePoint 2007. The URL is http://abcd:24931/docu/Forms/AllItems.aspx.

I need to display these documents in a data grid view of a Windows form application. I've written:

```
SPSite siteurl = new SPSite("http://abcd:24931/docu/Forms/AllItems.aspx");
```

But here (while debugging) the siteurl object does not contain the above complete URL. It only contains http://abcd:24931.

This is my big problem, please provide a solution for my code.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot take a document library's full url into a new SPSite object, that object can only take in a url to a SiteCollection.

What you can do, is getnan SPList instance of your document library then use the .Site property to get the SPSite object you want.